# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - dealing with dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, callback, plotly-dash

I'm having the error below with a project and looked for some explanation (like [this page](https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str/)) and I get the cause of the error. But I couldn't figure out what might be the problem in this case.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 688, in n_protocolo_callback
    g1, quantidades = graficos(
  File "', line 51, in graficos
    desejados = ids[ids["ID"] == numero]["Protocolo"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

some background to line 688:

```
def n_protocolo_callback(data, laudos, idade, sexo, operacao, pagina, quais_graficos):

    idade = faixas_idades.get(idade)
    idade_inicial, idade_final = None, None
    sexo = sexos.get(sexo)
    if idade:
        idade_inicial, idade_final = idade
    ids = laudos

    dados.loc[:, "Data"] = pd.to_datetime(dados.loc[:, "Data"])
    # cria primeiro gráfico
    g1, quantidades = graficos(
        dados, ids, data, laudos, [idade_inicial, idade_final], sexo
    )
```

beginnig of func: graficos()

```
def graficos(dados, ids, data, laudos, idade, sexo):
    data_inicial, data_final = data
    idade_inicial, idade_final = idade
    figura = []
    n_laudos = [numeros_diagnosticos.get(laudo) for laudo in laudos]
    mostrar = []

    for i, (nome, numero) in enumerate(zip(laudos, n_laudos)):
        desejados = ids[ids["ID"] == numero]["Protocolo"]
```

Edit: "ids" is a csv with 2 columns (ID and Protocolo) that's read by `pd.read_csv`. "numero" is an integer and "nome" a string

I think the problem has to do with indexing ids with "ID", but I'm not sure if that's right or how to solve it

Comment: How is `ids` declared?
If it's a two dimensional list, then the issue is with `['Protocolo']` but without seeing `ids` it's difficult to tell

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, I'll edit the question

Comment: And `numero` is an integer value?
i can't replicate the error

Comment: @Wolric the code is really big so I didn't post everythin, i know that doesn't help sorry. But numero is an integer and nome the string related to it.

Comment: if `ids` is the result of `pd.read_csv` then the issue is at another part of your code.
I created a csv file with two columns. Using your `ids[ids["ID"] == numero]["Protocolo"]` call did not end in a `TypeError` message for me.

Comment: @Wolric I'm workin on a coworker's code so it's a bit confusing. If "ids" is a two dimensional list then I should access "Protocolo" in a different way? Not through a string

Comment: Why do you set `ids = laudos` before you call `graficos`?

Comment: It worked! The problem was with the variable names. The "ids" should be a global variable (the df as I mentioned), but the function was calling another "ids". 
I actually don't know why it was set ids=laudos, but I deleted that and it's all right. Thank you very very much for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables can be accessed inside of functions as long as they are on the right side of an assignment:

```py
# Global variable
x = 3

def fun():
   # assign value of global variable x to local variable y
   y = x
```

If, however you have a variable with the same name of a global variable on the left side of an assignment, you'll create a local variable inside your function:

```py
# Global variable
x = 3

def fun():
   # Initialize local variable
   x = 5
   print(x)

print(x)  # prints 3
fun()     # prints 5
print(x)  # prints 3
```

`fun()` assigns a different value to `x` but it doesn't affect the global variable outside.

If you define a function, all parameters are of local scope.
When you pass those arguments to a function, Python checks in the current scope for all variable names and only goes to the next scope if it doesn't find all variables.

```py
# Global variabl
x = 3

def outer():
   def inner(x):
      print(x)
   inner(x)

outer()  # Prints 3
```

Try to avoid using `global` variables as they obfuscate your code.
I removed the parts not affecting your outcome for this explanation:

```py
import pandas as pd

# global variables
ids = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "Protocolo":[444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999,]})

# Presumably some list as this caused your TypeError
laudos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


def n_protocolo_callback(laudos):
    # Initialize a local variable ids with values from laudos
    ids = laudos
    # Calling graficos with local variable of ids
    g1, quantidades = graficos(ids, laudos)


# Define local variable of ids in the scope of function graficos
def graficos(ids, laudos):
    n_laudos = [numeros_diagnosticos.get(laudo) for laudo in laudos]

    for i, (nome, numero) in enumerate(zip(laudos, n_laudos)):
        # Accessing local variable ids
        desejados = ids[ids["ID"] == numero]["Protocolo"]

# Calling n_protocolo_callback will cause a TypeError
# n_protocolo_callback(laudos)
```

The error is caused as you re-assigned `ids` with the values of `laudos` inside `n_protocolo_callback` and then passed the local variable to `graficos`.

When you use `global` variables you don't need to add them as parameter to your function.

---

The `TypeError` is caused as a `list` can't be indexed with a string.
As the error message reads you can index either using integer or slices, i.e:

```py
l = [555, 666, 777, 888, 999]

# Accessing first element using integer
print(l[0])  # prints 555

# Accessing first 3 elements using slice:
print(l[0:3])  # prints [555, 666, 777]
```